# Why doesn't the string class have a << operator (operator<<) predefined so that strings work like ostringstreams?

Tags: c++

It seems to me that defining the << operator (operator<<) to work directly with strings is more elegant than having to work with ostringstreams and then converting back to strings. Is there a reason why c++ doesn't do this out of the box?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> 
string& operator<<(string& s, T a) {
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    s.append(ss.str());
    return s;
}
int main() {
    string s;
    // this prints out: "inserting text and a number(1)"
    cout << (s << "inserting text and a number (" << 1 << ")\n");

    // normal way
    ostringstream os; 
    os << "inserting text and a number(" << 1 << ")\n";
    cout << os.str();
}
```

Comment: Well, then you have to implement all manipulators (you know, the small functions you use to set e.g. field width) all over again. Code duplication is a terrible waste.

Comment: Besides, with the new C++11 standard it's less of a problem since you can use [`operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) together with [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the idea of strings being output streams is that they would become too heavy.

Strings are intended to "hold string data", not to format some output. Output streams have a heavy "state" which can be manipulated (see `<iomanip>`) and thus has to be stored. This means that, of course, this has to be stored for *every* string in every program, but almost none of them are used as an output stream; so it's a huge waste of resources.

C++ follows the "zero overhead" design principle (or at least no more overhead than totally necessary). Not having a string class which doesn't add any unnecessary overhead would be a huge violation of this design principle. If this was the case: what would people do in overhead-critical cases? Use C-strings... ouch!

In C++11, an alternative is to use the [`operator+=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+=) with [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to append to a string, which can also be chained like the `operator<<` of the output stream. You can wrap both `+=` and `to_string` in a nice `operator<<` for string if you like:

```
template <class Number> 
std::string& operator<<(std::string& s, Number a) {
    return s += std::to_string(a);
}
std::string& operator<<(std::string& s, const char* a) {
    return s += a;
}
std::string& operator<<(std::string& s, const std::string &a) {
    return s += a;
}
```

Your example, updated using this method: **http://ideone.com/4zbVtD**

Answer (score 3):

Streams contain additional state.  Imagine if this were possible:

```
std::string str;
int n = 1234;
str << std::hex;
str << n;
return str; // returns "0x4d2" (or something, I forget)
```

In order to maintain this additional state, strings would have to have storage for this state.  The C++ standards committee (and C++ programmers in general) have generally frowned upon superfluous resource consumption, under the motto "pay only for what you use".  So, no extra fields in the string class.

**The subjective answer:** is that I think the `std::string` class was quite poorly designed to begin with, especially compared to other parts of C++'s excellent standard library, and adding features to `std::string` is just going to make things worse.  This is a very subjective opinion and feel free to dismiss me as a raving lunatic.

Answer (score 0):

Probably lost in the depths of time now but formatted output was *always* associated with streams in C (since they didn't have "real" strings) and this may have been carried over into C++ (which was, after all, C with classes). In C, the way to format to a string is to use `sprintf`, a variation on `fprintf`, the output-to-stream function.

Obviously conjecture on my part but someone probably thought similarly to yourself that these formatting things in the streams would be brilliant to have on strings as well, so they subclassed the stream classes to produce one that used a string as it's "output".

That seems the elegant solution to getting it working as quickly as possible. Otherwise, you would have had formatting code duplicated in streams and strings.